# На сервере сайта создается html страница!

Tags: php, html

Доброго времени суток!

Сразу к делу. Лабаю сайт, нужно сделать подобие каталога товаров. Есть страница со списком товаров, и если юзер кликает на товар - естественно, появляется страница, посвященная данному товару! Обычно это делается через GET, то есть 1 страница, и в зависимости от id, переданного через GET, выгружается из БД нужная информация о товаре. НО я на многих сайтах видел, что там не используют данный метод, вместо этого там на каждый товар своя html страница.

Вот у меня вопрос: видимо, есть какая-то функция в PHP, скажем, которая генерирует html странице на сервере и наполняет их нужной инфой, не подскажите, что за функция? Вот, к примеру, тут так: http://www.lessons-tva.info/articles/net/002.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется [ЧПУ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%CF%D3_(%C8%ED%F2%E5%F0%ED%E5%F2)). Get запрос в таком случает все равно передается. Как реализовать ЧПУ и что это такое, можно почитать [тут](http://www.phpinfo.su/articles/practice/chpu_na_php.html)

Answer (score 0):

Максимально подробно описано [тут](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/), ну а в общем этим занимается [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), поэтому советую копать в его сторону. Конкретного ответа дать не могу, этим не занимаюсь, но хоть направлю в какую-то сторону. :)